# Information about request body in controller action

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-2.0

I have the following method in my api-controller:

```
[HttpPut("{id}")]
public IActionResult Put(int id, [FromBody]MyModel model)
{
    if (!ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        return BadRequest();
    }
    // Here I want to know more about model.SomeReferenceId
    return NoContent();
}
```

MyModel:

```
public class MyModel
{
    [Required]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public int? SomeReferenceId { get; set; }
}
```

Now I want to know if `SomeReferenceId` was included in the request but had an null value, or if `SomeReferenceId` was not included in the request at all.

Basically I want to know if the request body was

```
{
    Name: "Some Name",
    SomeReferenceId: null
}
```

or

```
{
    Name: "Some Name"
}
```

Comment: what difference does it make further down the line?

Answer (score 0):

I'm inclined to agree with user12345, why does it make a difference?

If you absolutely must know you could read the raw body as a string and check the content.

```
using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(Request.Body, Encoding.UTF8))
{  
    var rawBody = reader.ReadToEnd();
    // check rawBody for presence of field
}
```